# DispatcherOperation.Task returning immediately

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, dispatcher

I have a WPF application where I press a button and the following code executes:

```
private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    new Thread(
        async () =>
            {
                Action lambda = async () =>
                    {
                        await Task.Delay(5000);
                        MessageBox.Show("Lambda done");
                    };
                await this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, lambda).Task;
                MessageBox.Show("Dispatch done");
            }).Start();
}
```

[MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcheroperation.task(v=vs.110).aspx) of `DispatcherOperation.Task` says : `Gets a Task<TResult> that represents the current operation.` (It's not a `Task<TResult>` tho :/)
So I thought awaiting this would mean that the `MessageBox.Show("Dispatch done");` will only be executed after the lambda is finished. However, it is not the case. The MessageBox with "Dispatch done" text is shown as soon as the button is pressed, and the one with "Lambda done" text is shown 5 seconds after, as expected.

Can someone explicate this? I don't understand why it is happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This line:

```
Action lambda = async ...
```

is creating an `async void` lambda rather than an `async Task` lambda. One of the (many) problems with `async void` is that there is no (easy) way to tell when it completes. For this reason, ["avoid async void" is one of the best practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) in my MSDN article on the subject.

I haven't tried it, but I suspect that `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` can only take `Action` delegates (and not the more async-friendly `Func<Task>`), in which case it may be better to use `Dispatcher.Invoke` and pass a `Func<Task>`. In my own code, though, I avoid `Dispatcher` entirely; I find it encourages worse code. Instead of `Dispatcher`, consider using `await` and/or `Progress<T>`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So I changed the lambda to return a Func<Task> and used `Dispatcher.Invoke`. Now this works as expected :)
So I thought about it and deduced this: when it reaches the `await Task.Delay`, the lambda returns to wpf message loop and the `Dispatcher.Invoke` also returns, again, as the `Dispatcher.Invoke` is awaited, it returns to the created Thread? Why doesn't the thread end?

Comment: Also, when I replace `Dispatcher.Invoke` with `Dispatcher.InvokeAsync` which has the same parameters, the behaviour with async void is observed even when it is async Task now and it is awaited :/

Comment: @EmpereurAiman: I think it's confusing because what the dispatcher is doing "asynchronously" is just a synchronous operation. The `Invoke` works because we're doing an asynchronous operation synchronously. In other words, `BeginInvoke` returns a task that only represents the synchronous portion of the lambda (the invoke task). `Invoke` returns the lambda's task itself, which is what we want. `InvokeAsync` returns the lambda's task wrapped within the invoke task, so it would work but you'd have to double-`await` or call `Unwrap`.

Comment: thanks a lot again. I understand it now.
What about the question in my first comment? 
If I am awaiting in a new thread, why doesn't the thread end since the execution returns to the thread? Does the thread also have some kind of a "message loop"? Sorry for my noobiness

Comment: @EmpereurAiman: The thread will end. The outer `await` will run on a thread pool thread, not the `Thread` you created.

Comment: @EmpereurAiman: Sorry, I meant the outer `await` will *resume* on a thread pool thread. Not "run".